# Setting a bit of an integer from 0 to 1

Tags: c, pointers, bitwise-or

I've included the whole code below, but the only thing I'm wondering about is the `setBit` function. `x = 1 << bitNum` would just shift 0001 however many spaces  to the left depending on what number `bitNum` is but I don't understand the last line `(*u |= x)` Why is a pointer used here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

int checkBit(uint u, uint bitNum);

void setBit(uint* u, uint bitNum);

int countOnes(uint u);

int main()

{
    uint xxx, bitNumber;

    printf("\n Enter decimal integer xxx: ");
    scanf("%u", &xxx);
    printf("\n xxx in decimal: %u", xxx);
    printf("\n xxx in hex: %x", xxx);

    ////// Test countOnes function /////////////
    printf("\n Number of ones in xxx: %d", countOnes(xxx));

    ////// Test checkBit function /////////////
    printf("\n Enter bit to check: ");
    scanf("%u", &bitNumber);
    printf("\n Bit %d is %d", bitNumber, checkBit(xxx, bitNumber));
    printf("\n Enter bit to check: ");
    scanf("%u", &bitNumber);
    printf("\n Bit %d is %d", bitNumber, checkBit(xxx, bitNumber));

    ////// Test setBit function /////////////
    printf("\n Enter bit to set: ");
    scanf("%u", &bitNumber);
    printf("\n Setting bit %d of xxx", bitNumber);
    setBit(&xxx, bitNumber);
    printf("\n xxx in hex: %x", xxx);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int countOnes(uint u)
{
   int bitCount;

   for(bitCount = 0; u; u = u >> 1)
   {
       bitCount += u & 1;
   }

   return bitCount;
}

void setBit(uint* u, uint bitNum)
{
    int x;   
    x = 1 << bitNum;
    *u |= x;

}

int checkBit(uint u, uint bitNum)
{
    int x = u >> bitNum;

    if(x & 1 == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *u is used to set the bit of integer pointed by u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is a pointer used here?

Without having that pointer argument, the change to the desired variable won't be reflected in `main()`.

FYI, `C` uses pass-by-value in paramter passing. So, you need to pass the address of the variable and collect the same in a pointer to get the changes reflected to the actual variable in `main()`.

As per the code logic stands, your received parameter is `uint* u`. so to operate on the *value at the address held by the pointer*, you need the dereference operator `*`. Actually

```
*u |= x;
```

behaves like

```
(*u) |= x;
```

because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), which is basically telling

*"get the value at address pointed by u and OR it with the value in x and store it into the address pointed by u"*

Answer (score 2):

```
*u |= x;
```

Above line ORs the integer pointed by u with bitmask x.

As setBit() receives the pointer to integer (uint *u). To change that integer you have to address it as *u

Answer (score 0):

> (*u |= x). Why is a pointer used here?

In the above statement, `u` is pointer but when you place a indirection operator `*` in front of pointer `u`, such as `*u`, you're dereferencing the pointer retrieving value *pointed to* by the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is most likely used to reduce repetition. The alternative is:

```
uint setBit (uint u, uint bitNum)

xxx = setBit (xxx, bitNumber);
```

If you're only going to use it to set a bit in place, then the pointer avoids having to specify the name of the variable twice. Also, it also avoids the possibility of accidentally creating code that does nothing, like this:

```
setBit (xxx, bitNumber);
```

This would do nothing at all since the return value was ignored. With the function taking a pointer, this mistake is impossible to make.